# Adding an action to many cases in a LabVIEW case structure

Tags: case, labview

Can you add an action to multiple cases in a LabVIEW case structure?

I have a situation where I have already created a case structure with many cases. I need to add another output tunnel, but I am stuck needing to wire each case. Is there a way to tell LabVIEW to wire all of the cases and then manually change the few that are different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is. In recent LabVIEW version (>2011 I think), you can create a 'Linked input tunnel', to do so create a left-to-right wire in one case, right click the the right-hand terminal, and select 'Linked Input Tunnel->Create & Wire Unwired Cases'. This will add the wire to all the cases **and to new cases you add later**:

[image]